# How to call a non constant function instead of const function?

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions:

```
const Node* Find(const T& data, const Node* start = nullptr) const;
Node* Find(const T& data, Node* start = nullptr);
```

How do I or the compiler chooses when to call one over the other? I'm getting errors because the const version is being called instead of the non const versio.

Comment: are these class member functions? In any case, please post a [mcve] and include the error messages in the question

Answer (score 1):

> How do I or the compiler chooses when to call one over the other?

The choice is based on the type of the object operand. Non-const overload is preferred for non-const values and const overload is the only option for const values.

> How to call a non constant function instead of const function?

Call the function with a non-const object operand.